# How to type a custom LinkComponent that uses useLinkProps hook?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In the React Navigation documentation the `Link` component receives a bunch of parameters and some are passed to the `useLinkProps` hook. What types am I supposed to use to type these parameters?

I've looked into the source code of the `Link` component but when typing the `to` parameter it imports the `To` type from `@react-navigation/native/lib/typescript/src/useLinkTo`, and based on the length of the import I'd assume that this wouldn't be an official way to type the parameter.